Combining multiple rows and columns in one cell (merged cell) without losing the text new line
As per the subject, does anyone know how to combine rows of text and automatically get a new line when another row is added? Here's an example:
INPUT TABLE:



+
A
B
C




1
ORDER ID
Original Currency
To USD


2
123ABC
SAR 123.00
$33.21


3
456DEF
SAR 43.00
$11.61


4
246HIJ
SAR 54.00
$14.58



OUTPUT (to be in a single merged cell):



+
F




1
RESULT/OUTPUT


2
123ABC - SAR 123.00 - $33.21456DEF - SAR 43.00 - $11.61246HIJ - SAR 54.00 - $14.58




It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

oh here, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GIdpDuTJq1Y__xXA79ALyFPztWzaMp5OA7BagEkMO-g/edit?usp=sharing

your question also seems to showcase a scenario where one of the cells is blank & its being replaced with zero in the final output?!

Oh yes, basically, I have a formula/data checking on the Columns B and C so when they are empty, it is replaced with 0. Sorry. Please understand.

Can you also add such scenarios to the test sheet along with the expected output?!

Apologize for the wait. Correction, I only have a validation for Column C. B is user input so it will never be empty. Actually, we can forget the data validation, once rows A, B, and C have values, it will add to the Result. It should not be added if one of them is empty. Is it possible?


You may try:
=join(char(10),filter(A2:A&" - "&switch(to_text(B2:B),"",0,to_text(B2:B))&" - "&switch(to_text(C2:C),"",0,to_text(C2:C)),byrow(A2:C,lambda(Σ,counta(Σ)=3))))



Use textjoin() and byrow(), like this:
=textjoin(char(10), true, 
  byrow(A2:C, lambda(row, 
    textjoin(" - ", true, row) 
  )) 
)

See
textjoin()
and
byrow().
